# File encryption in Laravel and sudo users

Tags: linux, laravel, encryption, storage

I understand I can encrypt and store the contents of files (csv mainly) using the techniques explained  [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption) and [here](https://stefanzweifel.io/posts/how-to-encrypt-file-uploads-with-laravel).

However, I am looking for a way to prevent anyone from accessing these files, even users with sudo access to the server. The only one (or group of people) who should be able to access the encrypted files would be those who have a password or encryption key chosen by me. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

By default the file will show encrypted data, hence even if the file anyone get cant seen data. however you can also put key protectection using class from Encrypt directly or using spatie crypt

Here LOOK  [Spatie link](https://laravel-news.com/encrypt-and-decrypt-data-using-keys)

You can also use the default crypt like this

```
    use Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter;

//Keys and cipher used by encrypter(s)
$fromKey = base64_decode("from_key_as_a_base_64_encoded_string");
$toKey = base64_decode("to_key_as_a_base_64_encoded_string");
$cipher = "AES-256-CBC"; //or AES-128-CBC if you prefer

//Create two encrypters using different keys for each
$encrypterFrom = new Encrypter($fromKey, $cipher);
$encrypterTo = new Encrypter($toKey, $cipher);

//Decrypt a string that was encrypted using the "from" key
$decryptedFromString = $encrypterFrom->decryptString("gobbledygook=that=is=a=from=key=encrypted=string==");

//Now encrypt the decrypted string using the "to" key
$encryptedToString = $encrypterTo->encryptString($decryptedFromString);
```